# Spark: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3:///<bucket-name>

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

I have written a sample Spark program in Scala to count the number of lines of a text file present in Amazon S3. Below is my sample program.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import java.util.{Map => JMap}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
object CountLines {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("CountLines").setMaster("local"))
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","ABC");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey","XYZ");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId","ABC");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","XYX");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
val path ="s3:///my-bucket/test/test.txt";
println("num lines: " + countLines(sc, path));
}
def countLines(sc: SparkContext, path: String): Long = {
sc.textFile(path).count();
}
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting IllegalArgumentException which has something to do with credentials. Below is the stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3:/my-bucket/test/test.txt
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:45)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I have given valid credentials. I package this as a JAR file and run on the cluster using spark-submit command. I am not sure if this is the right way to set the access key and secret key in spark. I have tried different approaches but nothing seems to work. Throwing some light on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
J Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra slash. You have to change `s3:///my-bucket/test/test.txt` to `s3://my-bucket/test/test.txt`.